# SetTimeout() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Very simple task, refresh div after each 10 sec.

```
function upd(){
    alert('asd');
    $('#maincontent').load('providerpage.php?allimages=1 #maincontent > *');

}
window.onload=function(){
    setTimeout('upd()',10000);
}
```

Above construction doesn't work, plz tell me guys what is wrong with it. I put alert for testing and it displays only one time, at first iteration.

Comment: That's what `setTimeout()` does, runs the function once. You probably want `setInterval()`.

Comment: setTimeout only fires once. If you want to refresh repeatedly either use `setInterval()`, or call `setTimeout()` at the end of your `upd()` function.

Comment: @PraveenKumar setTimeout as I think, maybe I made the wrong synt.? Also console shows nothing

Comment: @Zheka `setTimeout()` fires only once, as Mike said. Use `setInterval()` instead. :)

Comment: thanks all, stupid mistake, setInterval works

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Juhana and others in the comments:

> That's what `setTimeout()` does, runs the function once. You probably
>   want `setInterval()`

I don't know why no one put that as an answer (instead of a comment) so he can accept the answer, and we all leave this question alone (instead of posting closing votes).

Zheka: you can also put the answer yourself once you know the solution if no one else does.